# Apache shows a directory listing instead of starting an application

Tags: apache

when i browse in localhost/PhpMyAdmin i see the content of the directory with the title:

Index of /PhpMyAdmin

instead of starting the application.
System info:
Windows 7 professional 64bit
Apache 2.2
PHP 5.3.5.0
MySql Server 5.6

PhpMyAdmin install from phpMyAdmin-4.2.10-all-languages.zip file

Same result using both config.default.php and config.inc.php in the PhpMyAdmin directory.
Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 5):

In your Apache configuration, find the line for `DirectoryIndex`. You'll need to add index.php to the list. For example, mine looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html home.pl index.cgi
```

You probably don't need all of those and should only add index.php; don't just copy and paste my line, it's just given as an example.

This is the list of files that Apache looks for to run as the main page of a folder/subdirectory. If it can't find any of the listed files then it generally shows the listing of all files in that directory (which is controlled by [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html), if you're interested in learning more).